# how do I understand the specific solution to one problem in hackerrank？

Tags: algorithm

It's about a solution to one problem in hackerrand. please click the link:

[the link of problem description](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reverse-shuffle-merge)

```
string reverseShuffleMerge(string s) {
int n = s.length();
vector<char> sarr(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
int alpha_size = 26;
vector<int> freq(alpha_size, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    freq[sarr[i] - 'a']++;
}
vector<int> did_use(alpha_size, 0);
vector<int> can_use(freq.begin(), freq.end());
vector<char> A;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (did_use[sarr[i] - 'a'] < freq[sarr[i] - 'a'] / 2) {
        while (A.size() > 0 && sarr[i] < A.back() 
               && did_use[A.back() - 'a'] + can_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1 
               >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2) {
            did_use[A.back() - 'a']--;
            A.pop_back();
        }
        A.push_back(sarr[i]);
        did_use[sarr[i] - 'a']++;
        can_use[sarr[i] - 'a']--;
    } else {
        can_use[sarr[i] - 'a']--;
    }
}
return string(A.begin(), A.end());
```

}

I don't get the point of this line: did_use[A.back() - 'a'] + can_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1 >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2

Could anyone help to shed some light on what part this line plays in the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, frequency of all the character in string **s** will be even number. The answer will contain half of these characters. For example if `s="aaaabbcc"`, then answer must contain `2` a, `1` b and `1` c.

So `did_use[A.back() - 'a'] + can_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1 >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2` this is for if we remove `A.back()` character, can we add/make required number of `A.back()` character in later with the remaining string.

Comment: but why - 1 is needed?

Comment: `did_use[A.back() - 'a']` contains the number of character `A.back()` already used, `can_use[A.back() - 'a']` contains the number of character `A.back()` remaining. Since we are trying to remove already added character `A.back()` from answer, so if we remove it, number of already used character `A.back()` will be `did_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1`.

Comment: but that is done with did_use[A.back() - 'a']--, isn't that? i still don't understand  did_use[A.back() - 'a'] + can_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1 >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2 well.

Comment: that is done with did_use[A.back() - 'a']--, that's right. but first you need to check can you remove the character? that's why `did_use[A.back() - 'a'] + can_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1 >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2`  condition is given.

Comment: i know we need to remove the already added char in this situation. but i have no clue why we have to -1 in did_use[A.back() - 'a'] + can_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1 >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2 when we want to check if the char can be removed.

Comment: why do you think `-1` not needed?

Comment: i am not sure. i just don't know why it is -1 rather than any other integer. i don't understand the logic of did_use[A.back() - 'a'] + can_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1 >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2 in here

Comment: `((did_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1) + can_use[A.back() - 'a'])  >= freq[A.back() - 'a'] / 2` . Since we are trying to remove already added character `A.back()` (one character)  from answer, so if we remove it, number of already used character A.back() will be `did_use[A.back() - 'a'] - 1`.

Comment: got it. Thanks a ton!